# Printing and sorting in java

Tags: java, printing

How would I do an additional method to print the output in an ordered, ascending sequence?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class LinLinkedList{
public static void main(String [] args){
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = 0;
    while (!(n<0)){
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        n = in.nextInt();
        list.add(n);
        }
    System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `if(n>0)` just before `list.add(n);` will solve it. Then you will have only positive values in your linked list. To sort your list in ascending order, you can use `Collections.sort(list);` as Guiilaume Polet suggested. After the while loop, use this sorting method and then print the contents of the linked list.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println(list.subList(0, list.size() - 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort your list, just call:

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

Comment: Isn't that what he asks in the last part of the question?

Comment: you are right, just have seen now. but you should make sure that it sorts in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
while (!(n<0)){
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    n = in.nextInt();
    list.add(n);
}
```

write

```
do{
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    n = in.nextInt();
    list.add(n);
} while (!(n<0));
```